# Почему jQuery не выдает никаких ошибок, если задать невалидный селектор?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Просто интересно, почему подобный код:

```
$(undefined).css({...})
```

или

```
$(123).css({...})
```

или

```
$(false).css({...})
```

не вызывает никаких ошибок в консоли, ведь это явно невалидные значения?

Comment: jQuery принимает на вход далеко не только селекторы: `$(function() {})`, `$('<div>')`, `$(<HTMLElement>)`, `$(<jQuery>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему невалидные значения? Просто это не селектор. Мы можем передать в функцию jQuery не только строку, но и [объект](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object). В ответ мы получим jQuery-объект, в котором будет доступна функция css, просто она ничего не будет модифицировать.